# How can I retrieve list members using given a unique_email_id on Mailchimp API v3?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Given a `unique_email_id`, how can I retrieve all list members matching that ID?

I am attempting to use the `search-members` endpoint, ala what I do for searching email-addresses:

```
https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?query=chris@chris.com
```

but instead (given a unique_email_id of 4dce5

```
https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/search-members?query=4dce5
```

and I'm getting no results.

Is there another endpoint I'm missing?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm having the same issue at the moment.

Comment: So far I have not. Mailchimp for whatever reason does not really support easily searching across lists.

Answer (score 6):

> However using the query string ?unique_email_id=X attached to the end
>   of GET lists/list_id/members will pull up anyone with that specific
>   EUID.

Indeed this works very well. Example :

```
GET /3.0/lists/dfc3cf4b38/members?unique_email_id=f4b75a9d78&fields=members.email_address
```

will return :

```
{"members":[{"email_address":"my_email@hotmail.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had a chat with the mailchimp support about this issue. This was there response (part of it because not everything discussed in that chat is relevant to this question):

> (09:00:04 AM) Mailchimp support: Thanks for hanging in there, Me. It looks like
> the email_unique_id can't be searched via API endpoint like it can be
> within the app. Another option to get to your goal is GET to
> lists/list_id/members with the query string
> ?fields=members.email_address,members.unique_email_id which should
> pull up all their subscribers' emails and unique ids. At that point,
> you can filter through those results for the unique id
>
> (09:00:52 AM) Me: Same goes for the user ID I guess?
>
> (09:02:05 AM) Me: Why  can't it be searched? When I list ids as well I might miss information. I don't need the unique_email_id in my response, I need to search for it to retrieve user information without getting duplicates in my result
>
> (09:07:11 AM) Mailchimp support: Ok I understand, one
> moment while we test this out for you. Thanks again for your patience!
>
> (09:16:22 AM) Mailchimp support: Hey Me, thanks for waiting. I tested the
> endpoint lists/list_id/members?unique_email_id=e8da8fa60a and  I was
> able to return just the one subscriber with that field. Search-Members
> only functions the way it does in app where you can only search
> specific strings like names, email addresses, but not ids as those
> aren't visible in app. However using the query string
> ?unique_email_id=X attached to the end of GET lists/list_id/members
> will pull up anyone with that specific EUID.